# How To Change Default Path Powershell Remote

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

How do I **permanently** change the default path based on the **PowerShell Remote** login profile?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.82 -Credential "MyUser"
[192.168.1.82]: PS C:\Users\MyUser\Documents>
```

I want this path after login

```
[192.168.1.82]: PS W:\MyWorks>
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You could create the session with `New-PSSession` and then issue a `cd W:\MyWorks` statement to the remote runspace before entering it:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.82 -Credential "MyUser"
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { cd W:\MyWorks }
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
```

Comment: i want it to be hidden for the user

Comment: @TachikomaWebI Sounds like you want a [constrained endpoint](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints/) on the target then...